# ASP.net Getting Max Date of database Date column How to avoid Null in Date Column C# My code Attached

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

i am trying to get last update DATE in database with in Date column my code is,

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 && (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString() != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString() != ""))
            {
                try
                {
                    DataColumn col = ds.Tables[0].Columns[4];
                    DataTable tbl = col.Table;
                    var LastUpdate = tbl.AsEnumerable()
                   .Max(r => r.Field<DateTime>(col.ColumnName));
                    date = LastUpdate.ToString();
                    value = date.Split(' ');
                    txtActivatedOn.Text = value[0];
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
```

Its a part of code simply getting column 4 from data base that is DATE column and getting last date inserted in that column it is giving accurate answer but it column contains null value it result in error

How to skip null value in that column while getting date ??

Hopes for your suggestion

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try check for null-values in a where condition first.

Changed the Datetime to the nullable DateTime? to make the check for nullvalues work.

```
    var LastUpdate = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<DateTime?>(col.ColumnName) != null).Max(r => r.Field<DateTime>(col.ColumnName));
```

Comment: @user802782: Do you get any exception messages that might help?

Comment: r.Field<DateTime>(col.ColumnName) will fail if the value is null. DateTime is a value type and cannot be null.

Comment: That's a good point ! I changed the DataType to the nullable "DateTime?" so this shouldn't fail anymore. Nevertheless your updated answer is a little more elegant :)

Comment: Could you post any further information e.g. an exception message? You could try Guillaumes attempt as well.

Answer (score 1):

As abeldenibus said, you should filter out null values in a where condition but Field extension method is not well suited for this task.

```
var LastUpdate = tbl.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => !r.IsNull(col))
    .Max(r => r.Field<DateTime>(col));
date = LastUpdate.ToString();
```

Comment: I think he just needs to check for null-values in this specific column and not if the whole DataRow is null. That's why i added the field extension. Correct me if I'm wrong but I think your expression checks if the whole row is null.